# Dynamic ROOT With SQL Server For JSON PATH

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a keyword table that I want to render to a Json object:

```
ID  Keyword     Text    Value
4   Category    A       10
5   Category    B       20
1   Season      Winter  1
2   Season      Spring  2
3   Season      Summer  3
9   Season      Fall    4
6   UnitType    Ft      Feet
7   UnitType    Set     Set
8   UnitType    $   Dollar
```

that groups each category into it's own object.

I've being able to create this:

```
{"Keywords":[
{"Keyword":"Category","Values":[{"Value":"10","Text":"A"},{"Value":"20","Text":"B"}]},
{"Keyword":"Season","Values":[{"Value":"1","Text":"Winter"},{"Value":"2","Text":"Spring"},{"Value":"3","Text":"Summer"},{"Value":"4","Text":"Fall"}]},
{"Keyword":"UnitType","Values":[{"Value":"Dollar","Text":"$"},{"Value":"Feet","Text":"Ft"},{"Value":"Set","Text":"Set"}]}
]}
```

using:

```
SELECT T.Keyword AS 'Keyword', 
(SELECT [subT].[Value] AS 'Value', [subT].[Text] AS 'Text' 
FROM tblKeywords subT WHERE subT.Keyword=T.Keyword 
ORDER BY [subT].[Value]
FOR JSON PATH) AS 'Values'
FROM tblKeywords T
GROUP BY T.Keyword
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Keywords')
```

But I'd like to be able to set the ROOT for the sub query to be keyword itself. Is this even possible?

The desired result is:

```
{"Keywords":[
{"Category":[{"Value":"10","Text":"A"},{"Value":"20","Text":"B"}]},
{"Season":[{"Value":"1","Text":"Winter"},{"Value":"2","Text":"Spring"},{"Value":"3","Text":"Summer"},{"Value":"4","Text":"Fall"}]},
{"UnitType":[{"Value":"Dollar","Text":"$"},{"Value":"Feet","Text":"Ft"},{"Value":"Set","Text":"Set"}]}
]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible approach using combination of `FOR JSON` and string manipulation, but without dynamic statement:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblKeywords (
   Id int, 
   [Keyword] nvarchar(50), 
   [Text] nvarchar(50), 
   [Value] nvarchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO #tblKeywords
   (ID, [Keyword], [Text], [Value])
VALUES
   (4, 'Category', 'A',      '10'),
   (5, 'Category', 'B',      '20'),
   (1, 'Season',   'Winter', '1'),
   (2, 'Season',   'Spring', '2'),
   (3, 'Season',   'Summer', '3'),
   (9, 'Season',   'Fall',   '4'),
   (6, 'UnitType', 'Ft',     'Feet'),
   (7, 'UnitType', 'Set',    'Set'),
   (8, 'UnitType', '$',      'Dollar')
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
   N'{"Keywords":[',
   STUFF(
      (
      SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(N',{"', k.[Keyword], '":', c.[Json], N'}')
      FROM #tblKeywords k
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT [Value], [Text]
         FROM #tblKeywords
         WHERE [Keyword] = k.[Keyword]
         FOR JSON PATH
      ) c([Json])
      FOR XML PATH('')
      ), 1, 1, N''
   ),  
   N']}'
) AS JsonOutput
```

Output:

```
JsonOutput

{"Keywords":[{"Category":[{"Value":"10","Text":"A"},{"Value":"20","Text":"B"}]},{"Season":[{"Value":"1","Text":"Winter"},{"Value":"2","Text":"Spring"},{"Value":"3","Text":"Summer"},{"Value":"4","Text":"Fall"}]},{"UnitType":[{"Value":"Feet","Text":"Ft"},{"Value":"Set","Text":"Set"},{"Value":"Dollar","Text":"$"}]}]}
```

Comment: This is a great approach also. It looks like I still have a lot to learn about what MSSQL can do. I've been stuck in DB2 for years and I'm just getting back into it. This is good stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Initial data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblKeywords;
CREATE TABLE #tblKeywords (ID INT, Keyword NVARCHAR(255), [Text] NVARCHAR(255), Value NVARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO #tblKeywords(ID,Keyword,Text,[Value])VALUES
     (4,'Category','A','10')
    ,(5,'Category','B','20')
    ,(1,'Season','Winter','1')
    ,(2,'Season','Spring','2')
    ,(3,'Season','Summer','3')
    ,(9,'Season','Fall','4')
    ,(6,'UnitType','Ft','Feet')
    ,(7,'UnitType','Set','Set')
    ,(8,'UnitType','$','Dollar')
;
```

I know, Dynamic SQL, however:

```
DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT 'SELECT ' + STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT N',(SELECT [subT].[Value] AS [Value], [subT].[Text] AS [Text] 
            FROM #tblKeywords subT 
            WHERE subT.Keyword = ''' + t.Keyword + N''' 
            ORDER BY [subT].[Value]
            FOR JSON PATH
            ) AS [' + t.Keyword + N']' + CHAR(13) + '   '
            FROM #tblKeywords t
            FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
        + 'FOR JSON PATH, ROOT(''Keywords'')'
)
;
--PRINT @DynSql;
EXEC (@DynSql);
```

Comment: Awesome. This is sooo close. It's creating an array of one object with properties. I'm upvoting though because I definitely think this is a good approach. I'm going to wrestle with this tomorrow and see if I can't dial it in. I'll report back with a final solve when I get it. Thanks!